# Calculating a percentile for a slice in a curve fit

Tags: standard-deviation, curve-fitting, scipy

Currently I have a of around 20000 datapoints, with the independent variable being time and the dependent variable being an arbitrary skill measure [Image 1]. I have fit a curve to the data using python's Scipy library and its curve_fit function.

Although the curve looks fine, I want to be able to tell what percentile of data a given datapoint is for a slice in the time. I've tried this using the standard deviations given by curve_fit and using it to plot curves that are one or two deviations away from the mean of the parameter. But plotting this results in a very narrow interval and even a -2 to 2 deviation contains only 60% of the datapoints although I would expect around 95% due to it being 2 deviations [Image 2].

So using this dataset, could I find the predicted mean and standard deviation at, for example, time = 1000, and all other times, if I were to assume Gaussian distribution?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am not sure I correctly understand this question because it's hard to relate your (unlabeled) plots to phrases like "slice in time" and what you might mean by "percentile of data."  Are you perhaps trying to estimate conditional distributions of the responses at each time? If so, how do you want those estimates to be related to the "curve fit," whatever that might be?  (You describe fitting "a curve" but you display five of them.)

Comment: Essentially the x axis here is time, and the 5 curves are my futile attempt at making confidence intervals. I believe the conditional distribution is correct. Essentially, with the data at hand, I'm trying to get the distribution for a given time, x, so that if a new datapoint were to come in, say (1000, 10000), I can give that point a percentile within that distribution at time = 1000. What I don't understand how to do is get that distribution at a certain point in the x axis.

Comment: This is the general question of *regression:* how to estimate the conditional distribution.  The most powerful methods use parametric models because they can exploit those model assumptions.  You likely have enough data to make nonparametric estimates, but it's unclear whether you are willing to do that; or, if not, just what models you have in mind.  It's also unclear whether your data are independent or, possibly, reflect multiple time series in which there are strong interdependencies. It would help to give us some context and details.